# how to run a script on rails server using capistrano?

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I have written a script named `mailman_server` using `gem "mailman"` placed in 'script/mailman_server'

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
    require "rubygems"
    require "bundler/setup"
    require "mailman"

    #Mailman.config.logger = Logger.new("log/mailman.log")
    Mailman.config.poll_interval = 3
    Mailman.config.pop3 = {
      server: 'server', port: 110,
      username: "loginid",
      password: "password"
    }

    Mailman::Application.run do
      default do
        p "Found a new message"
        # 'perform some action here'
        end
    end
```

It fetches all the emails from my account and then i do processing on them.

I have my `deploy.rb` file as

```
set :stages, %w(production)     #various environments
load "deploy/assets"                    #precompile all the css, js and images... before deployment..
require "bundler/capistrano"            # install all the new missing plugins...
require 'delayed/recipes'               # load this for delayed job..
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'     # deploy on all the servers..
require "rvm/capistrano"                # if you are using rvm on your server..
require './config/boot'           
require 'airbrake/capistrano'           # using airbrake in your application for crash notifications..

set :delayed_job_args, "-n 2"            # number of delayed job workers 


before "deploy:assets:symlink", "deploy:copy_database_file"
before "deploy:update_code",  "delayed_job:stop"  # stop the previous deployed job workers...
after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start" #start the delayed job 
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart" # restart it..
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup" #clean up temp files etc.
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'             # ruby version you are using...
set :rvm_type, :user

server "my_server_ip", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true 

set(:application) { "my_application_name" }
set (:deploy_to) { "/home/user/#{application}/#{stage}" }
set :user, 'user'
set :keep_releases, 3
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:my_random_git_repo_url"
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, :git
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :git_enable_submodules, 1

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  task :copy_database_file do
    run "ln -sf #{shared_path}/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
```

I want to execute this script every time I deploy to the server. Also I need to stop this script whenever I am deploying the code.

I am unable to figure out how can we start or stop this script using capistrano on server.

Comment: How do you stop the script manually? Just by pressing Ctrl+C while it is processing? If that is the case, it would be a good idea to add another script to kill the process started by `mailman_server`, and invoke it from `before deploy` callback.

Comment: @Prakash yes I do that. Because I need that script to be running on server I have used screens.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save pid of process on start with something like this

```
run "cd #{deploy_to}/current; ./script/mailman_server &; echo &! > /var/run/mailman_server.pid" #untested
```

and stop it with

```
run "kill `cat /var/run/mailman_server.pid`;  rm /var/run/mailman_server.pid"
```

But I think you should check out [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html), it provides handy way to run jobs in development and supports exporting your jobs to upstart or inid.d scripts for production, so you will need just to start or stop corresponding service with

```
run "sudo /etc/init.d/mailman_server start"
run "sudo /etc/init.d/mailman_server stop"
```